# What is value shadowing?

Tags: c#, security, request, fortify

1. hi everyone

   ```
           private const string abc="__abc";
           private const string abcd="__abcd";


           pageLoad()
           {
           this.xyz();
           }

           xyz()
           {
           if postback()
           {
           }
           else
           {
           string k1=this.Request[abc];//some 'value shadowing error is           shown here by my tool . This makes it
   ```

   unsecure and vulnerable to user edits . 
               string k2=this.Request[abcd];//
               }
               }

   ```
       I want to resolve this issue but I am unsure about where to begin?

        - List item
   ```

Comment: Did you search "fortify value shadowing" on google? The first result is an explanation of this finding. I'm pretty sure a detailed explanation is included in the Fortify application also...

Answer (score 5):

As a short answer:
In the context of ASP.NET it means a user can pass in what is supposed to be let's say a form field as a query string parameter. 
To fix instead of going

```
Request["xyz"]
```

you go

```
Request.Form["xyz"]
```

You can read more here https://www.jardinesoftware.net/2011/06/07/asp-net-value-shadowing/